# Как правильно использовать токены отмены C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

Прочитав про токены отмены я не совсем понял как их правильно использовать в кастомных асинхронных методах. Например у меня сервис для работы с файлами кэша, асинхронный метод для поиска файла, он принимает токен отмены. Я в начале метода добавил `token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested()` и все. правильно ли это, если процесс уйдет дальше этого места, и произойдет отмена, эта строчка сработает или нет?

```
/// <summary>
/// Получает курс валюты по заданному типу из файла кэша на указанную дату.
/// Если нужного файла кэша нет, обращается к внешнему API и сохраняет кэш.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="type">Тип валюты (код)</param>
/// <param name="date">Нужная дата</param>
/// <param name="token">Токен отмены</param>
/// <returns>Курс нужной валюты на определенную дату</returns>
/// <exception cref="CurrencyNotFoundException">Если не найдена валюта заданного типа</exception>
public async Task<Currency> GetCurrencyOnDate(CurrencyType type, DateOnly date, CancellationToken token)
{
    token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
    
    var files = GetCachedFiles(DirectoryPath, token);
    var data = files != null ? await GetCacheOnDate(files, date, token) : null;

    if (data == null)
    {
        var response = await GetFromApiOnDate(date, token);
        var fileDate = response.Item1.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH-mm-ssZ");
        data = response.Item2;
        await SaveCacheJsonAsync($"{DirectoryPath}/{fileDate}.json", data);
    }

    var currency = data.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Code == type.ToString());
    if (currency == null)
        throw new CurrencyNotFoundException("Нет валюты с таким кодом! ");

    return currency;
}
```

Comment: Нет, насколько я понял, строчка срабатывает только там, где она стоит. Если у вас какой-то долгий цикл, то такая строчка должна внутри цикла стоять, как-то так.

Comment: @CrazyElf понял что не сработает. Если нет никакого цикла, просто вот метод как есть, как правильно тогда использовать, я что то не совсем понял

Comment: На эту тему есть много информации, как [официальной](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/standard/threading/cancellation-in-managed-threads), так и [сторонней](https://metanit.com/sharp/tutorial/12.5.php), странно что вы не поняли как с ними работать. Если коротко, то токен это простой объект, который знает о том, что была сделана отмена, проверив его вы можете сделать нужные действия (выбросить ошибку, или просто завершить работу), проверять должны каждую итерацию. Также вы должны его передавать во все методы, которые токен принимают (обычно асинхронные)

Comment: Если у вас нет тут никакого цикла, то лучше всего просто передать этот токен ещё дальше в асинхронные вызовы, которые вы тут делаете. Обычно асинхронные методы умеют принимать токен отмены как параметр и работать с ним. Но вообще, если ваш метод выполняется быстро, то скорее всего токен вам просто не нужен. В общем, я бы на вашем месте просто отдал токен дальше в асинхронные вызовы и всё. Собственно, я смотрю, вы это в основном уже и делаете.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ я понимаю как они работают. Что мне делать в случае когда методы кастомные, асинхронные и вложены друг в друга, и нет цикла. Обоснованно тогда использование строчки в начале метода, которая бросает исключение, или есть другой способ?

Comment: Зависит от логики вашего метода. Если вы там делаете долгую операцию, то вы должны предусмотреть там процесс отмены (как, опять зависит от вашего метода). Если это операция, которая выполняется моментально, то смысла в токене по сути и нету.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Помимо явного бросания исключения по токену вы ещё передаете его в другие методы, которые точно так же должны выбросить исключение в случаае отмены.

Вы не передаете токен только в метод `SaveCacheJsonAsync`, что является несовсем правильным. Поищите соответсвующую перегрузку.

С другой стороны, в самом начале метода стоит вызов синхронного `GetCachedFiles`, с токеном, поэтому ожидается, что метод должен бросить исключение, если  токен отменён ничего не делая. В этом случае строка `token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested()` - лишняя.

Смысл работы с токено в том, что в случае отмены нужно как можно скорее бросить исключение или прервать работу метода другим образом.

Если всё еще непонятно, то строка

```
token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
```

Это по сути вот что:

```
if (token.IsCancellationRequested)
    throw new OperationCanceledException();
```

Можно в [исходниках](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Threading/CancellationToken.cs#L359-L368) посмотреть.

Comment: Я понимаю смысл этих токенов - я не совсем понимаю как правильно использовать в случае, если все методы кастомные, то есть один вызывает другой, потом тот тоже другой и т.д. В таком случае обоснованно указание в начале строчки token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested() или все же нет, если циклов нет. Или вообще не стоит тогда использовать.

Comment: @Андрей Если я вызвал `.Cancel()` токену - всё должно сразу же завершиться, чем быстрее, тем лучше, в этом смысл. А не в том, какие строчки кода и где писать.

Comment: Это я понимаю, но как это обеспечить, например в том методе, что я описал, как постоянно проверять токен на отмену

Comment: @Андрей это уже вам решать, как. Все асинхронные методы в .NET поддерживают токен, не забывайте его туда передавать. В остальном зависит от ситуации. Вы разработчик, вам и решать, как оно должно работать.